# Retrieve all the API response while you have maximum offset in Python

Tags: python, api, loops, offset

I am attempting to retrieve data from this [API](https://apidoc.teltel.io/#get-/calls) that has a max offset of 200000. The records I am attempting to pull are more than the max offset. Below is a sample of the code I am using but when I reach the offset limit of 200000 it breaks (the API doesn't return any helpful response in terms of how many pages/requests I need to do that's why I am going until there are no more results ). I need to find a way to loop through and pull all the data. Thanks

```
def pull_api_data():
    offset_limit = 0
    teltel_data = []
    # Loop through the results and add if present
    while True:
        print("Skip", offset_limit, "rows before beginning to return results")
        querystring = {"offset": "{}".format(offset_limit), "filter": "starttime>="'{}'.format(date_filter), "limit" : "5000"}
        response = session.get(url=url, headers=the_headers, params=querystring)
        data = response.json()['data']

        # Do we have more data from teltel ?
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        # If yes ,then add the data to the main list ,teltel_data
        teltel_data.extend(data)
        # Increase offset_limit to skip the already added data
        offset_limit = offset_limit + 5000

    # transform the raw data by converting it to a dataframe and do necessary cleaning
    

pull_api_data()
```